# How to build a barcode generator?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want to make an app to generate barcode one by one for products based on the user inputs. The app should evenly distribute the products with same mode number, color and size among different stores.

Data model
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? You should try to code this for yourself (otherwise how should you learn if you just copy-paste the solution). Then you can show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and explain where the problem is and ask for some help.

Answer (score 1):

Add  import `'package:barcode/barcode.dart';` Library and then you can generate barcode like this.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:barcode/barcode.dart';

void buildBarcode(
  Barcode bc,
  String data, {
  String filename,
  double width,
  double height,
  double fontHeight,
}) {
  /// Create the Barcode
  final svg = bc.toSvg(
    data,
    width: width ?? 200,
    height: height ?? 80,
    fontHeight: fontHeight,
  );

  // Save the image
  filename ??= bc.name.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\s'), '-').toLowerCase();
  File('$filename.svg').writeAsStringSync(svg);
}

void main() {
  buildBarcode(
    Barcode.code39(),
    'CODE 39',
  );

  buildBarcode(
    Barcode.code93(),
    'CODE 93',
  );

  buildBarcode(
    Barcode.code128(useCode128B: false, useCode128C: false),
    'BARCODE\t128',
    filename: 'code-128a',
  );

  buildBarcode(
    Barcode.code128(useCode128A: false, useCode128C: false),
    'Barcode 128',
    filename: 'code-128b',
  );

  buildBarcode(
    Barcode.code128(useCode128A: false, useCode128B: false),
    '0123456789',
    filename: 'code-128c',
  );

  buildBarcode(
    Barcode.gs128(),
    '(420)22345(56780000000001)',
  );

  buildBarcode(
    Barcode.itf14(),
    '1540014128876',
  );

  buildBarcode(
    Barcode.ean13(drawEndChar: true),
    '590123412345',
  );

  buildBarcode(
    Barcode.ean8(drawSpacers: true),
    '9638507',
    width: 100,
  );

  buildBarcode(
    Barcode.ean2(),
    '05',
    width: 40,
  );

  buildBarcode(
    Barcode.ean5(),
    '52495',
    width: 60,
  );

  buildBarcode(
    Barcode.isbn(drawEndChar: true),
    '978316148410',
  );

  buildBarcode(
    Barcode.upcA(),
    '98765432109',
  );

  buildBarcode(
    Barcode.upcE(),
    '06510000432',
    width: 100,
  );

  buildBarcode(
    Barcode.telepen(),
    'Telepen',
  );

  buildBarcode(
    Barcode.qrCode(),
    'QR-Code',
    height: 200,
  );

  buildBarcode(
    Barcode.codabar(explicitStartStop: true),
    'A1234-5678B',
  );

  buildBarcode(
    Barcode.pdf417(),
    'PDF417',
    height: 30,
  );

  buildBarcode(
    Barcode.dataMatrix(),
    'Datamatrix',
    height: 200,
  );

  buildBarcode(
    Barcode.aztec(),
    'Aztec',
    height: 200,
  );

  buildBarcode(
    Barcode.rm4scc(),
    'RM4SCC',
    height: 50,
    fontHeight: 30,
  );

  buildBarcode(
    Barcode.itf(),
    '987234',
  );
}
```